# Populate Name field of bookmarks automatically

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I have been stung by a bug in Firefox that hasn't been fixed in nearly 6 years, though I wasn't aware of it until now.

The bug report is here:
"Name field of bookmarks saved via "Bookmark All Tabs" has '(null)' value if history is disabled or just in private browsing mode"

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=446171

I have a number of bookmarks (perhaps half of them) that do not have the Name field populated. To manually fix them would take hours. I have checked for a suitable add-in without success.

This might seem like a minor issue, but I became aware of the problem when I wanted to export my bookmarks to an html file as a backup. The resultant file does not display the corrupted entries. The html source of the file contains the URLs but that is not a user-friendly solution.

How can I auto-populate the missing values?

Comment: Similar problem after dragging and dropping many short-links into Firefox from elsewhere. I would like to replace the short-link name with the website name/title/description.